При post запросе обновляется страница и содержимое пропадает
разрабатываю todo-list, у которого есть 3 секции:

Хедер, в котором содержится форма с полем ввода куда должна записываться задача и кнопка, при нажатии на которую задача должна попадать в список дел
main часть, содержащая список дел
Футер, куда попадают выполненные задачи.
Также я создал фейковый api в папке с проектом - data.json
Суть проблемы в том, что при нажатии на кнопку добавления задачи, задача попадает в список дел, но страница почему-то обновляется и задача пропадает. А сам post запрос проходит и data.json появляется новая сущность.

    <header class="header">
        <div class="header__container _container">
            <form  name="task-form"  class="header__form">
                <input name="task-name" type="text" class="header__form-input" placeholder="Add a new task">
                <button type="submit"  class="header__form-button">+</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main class="tasks">
        <div class="tasks__container _container">
            <p class="tasks-todo">Tasks to do - <span class="tasks-todo-length"></span> </p>
            <ul class="tasks__list">
                
            </ul>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer class="completed-tasks">
        <div class="completed-tasks__container _container">
            <p class="tasks-done">Done - <span class="tasks-done-length"></span></p>
            <ul class="done-list">
                
            </ul>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <template id="task-template">
        <li class="todo-task task">
            <p class="task-text"></p>
            <div class="button__wrapper">
                    <button class="task-complete-button"></button>
                    <button class="task-delete-button"></button>
                </div>
        </li>
    </template>
    <template id="completed-task-template">
        <li class="todo-task task">
            <p class="task-text"></p>
        </li>
    </template>

JS:
    taskForm.addEventListener('submit', formAddTaskSubmit)

function formAddTaskSubmit(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    postRequest(taskInput.value)
    .then((data) =>
    {
        const taskContent = taskTemplate.querySelector('.todo-task').cloneNode(true)            // Клик по кнопке добавления задачи добавляет её в список задач
        const task = (taskContent.closest('.task'))
        tasksList.append(task)
        const taskText = (taskContent.querySelector('.task-text').textContent = data.title)
        taskForm.reset()
        taskTodoLength.textContent = tasksList.children.length
    })
}

function postRequest (inputValue) {
    return fetch('http://localhost:3000/todos', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            title: inputValue,
            completed: false
        })
    })
    .then(checkServerState)
}

function checkServerState(res) {
  if (res.ok) {
    return res.json();
  } else {
    return Promise.reject(`Ошибка ${res.status}`);
  }
}


Посмотрите на бэке, что там нет никакого перенаправления

Немного не понимаю, что подразумевается под бэком. Я создал себе сервер с помощью npx json-server,  в файле с проектом у меня api data.json, про какие перенаправления речь?

У вас написано taskForm.addEventListener .... откуда взялась переменная taskForm ?

В глобальной области видимости я определил форму и инпут
const taskForm = document.forms['task-form']
const taskInput = taskForm.elements['task-name']

Сам код рабочий. Нужно единственное пару вещей сделать: 1. убедиться, что html загружен раньше чем код ( на всякий случай инициализацию переменных сделать после DOMContentLoaded)  и 2.  желательно не использовать устаревшие конструкции поиска элементов и задать форме id и искать её либо getElementById либо querySelector... С инпутами так же.......... А код рабочий вполне

Так не страница обновляется, а формы сабмитят данные (отправка запроса формой это поведение по-умолчанию, оно реализуется браузером). Без указания назначения, сабмитит на актуальный URL, вот оно и выглядит как обновление страницы. Можно попробовать просто добавить формам атрибут action="javascript:void(0)", наверное поможет.

@yar85 у него evt.preventDefault(); в коде написано. оно вполне себе рабочее

@АлексейШиманский, ага, но надо заботиться о том чтобы обработчики навешивались рано, и чтобы скрипты не падали - только при выполнении этих условий событие будет глушиться. Атрибут же, начинает действовать с момента создания элемента в DOM (в случае изначального присутствия в разметке) и от состояния внешних скриптов не зависит.

Форме задал атрибут action="javascript:void(0)"
Не помогло

@yar85 не надо советовать костыли костыльные из прошлого тысячелетия...... то, что нужно сделать,  я написал для ТС в комментарии выше........ разве что ещё можно посоветовать воспользоваться делегированием события (чотбы не использовать domcontentloaded)

Хотя нет. Можно ещё посоветовать одно: если настоящий submit не используется, т.к. обработка происходит силами  js, то тогда кнопка с типом submit совершенно бесполезна и нужно делать обычную кнопку. Соответственно надо просто повесить обработчик клика на неё и работать с ней и кликом....... И раз уже не используется форма от слова совсем, то в ней нет никакого смысла тоже и можно её заменить на простой div и тогда мучений с обновлением вообще не будет

@АлексейШиманский, прежде всего, не надо пороть чушь, называя «костылями из прошлого тысячелетия» использование нормативного поведения атрибута в актуальном стандарте. Прием конечно не идеален, но он распространен в реальной практике. Плюс, то что автор это попробовал, дало доп.информацию о проблеме.    sakre_e, учитывая то что пример из вопроса (с +2 строками из твоего коммента) по факту не автосабмитит форму, и то что даже атрибут у тебя игнорируется (чего быть не может), стоит глянуть на DOM через devtools браузера и убедиться в том что документ соответствует исходнику.

На самом деле вся проблема заключалась в том, что я использовал расширение Live Server в Vs code из-за чего и пропадала сразу задача, но не упомянул об этом в вопросе потому что на момент написания вопроса не думал вообще, что он может быть причастен. Спасибо за ваши советы все равно!
